# Select last entry from spreedsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

So I have a Google Form dumping data into spreadsheet tab form responses 1.

[image]

I have created another tab labeled summary. I need to have the summary tab only show the latest entry for a given pilot and be sorted by the main column. My progress thus far is

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A2:J,
 "SELECT max(A), B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J group by B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't show only the latest time stamp and for some reason, the query has a weird effect of showing max in the formula cell with a spare row.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found/figured out the answer via another thread. My solution was: =FILTER('Form Responses 1'!A2:J, MATCH( 'Form Responses 1'!A2:A , QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A2:C , "select max(A) group by lower(C)" ) , FALSE ) )

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(A2:C5; "limit 1 offset "&(COUNT(A2:C5)-1))
```

[image: 4]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. https://imgur.com/a/sxOJ9Ne

I attached an image giving an example of what my response form would have. What I am actually needing is for it to return the latest timestamp of each unique pilot. So in my image it would need to return everything except for the Main AC Pilot BD 1/4/19 line.

Answer (score 0):

```
={{A1:J1}; {IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(QUERY({QUERY(QUERY(A2:J,
 "select *", 0),
 "select Col3,Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10 order by Col1 desc", 0), A2:A},
 "select Col1, count(Col11) where Col11 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col11)''", 0),
 "select Col1", 0),QUERY(QUERY(A2:J,
 "select *", 0),
 "select Col3,Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10 order by Col1 desc", 0),
 {2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 0)), )}}
```

[image: 4]

Answer (score 0):

```
={{A1:J1}; {FILTER(A2:J, MATCH(A2:A, QUERY(A2:C, "select max(A) group by lower(C)"), 0))}}
```

[image: 4]